# How to fill an image from bottom side until an edge is detected using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My goal is to be able to replicate obstacle avoidance method shown from this [link](http://www.roborealm.com/tutorial/Obstacle_Avoidance/slide010.php) using OpenCV 3. It seems like the software they provide is for Windows only. I think this is possible to replicate using OpenCV. I am currently at step 2 using Canny edge detection. I'm not sure what functions I can use to create step 3, where the image is filled from the bottom side until an edge is detected. Any reference material would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Robot View][image][image][image]

Comment: This will probably have an answer by the time I'm able to sit down and write up a solution, but the easiest thing to do would be to use `np.where()` to find the locations of all non-zero values in your binary image, and then find the maximum row index for each column in the result of where, and then set `image[max_row_index:, column] = 255` (or whatever appropriate white value for your image type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 0

This is the standard, loop-based method to complete this. The idea is to start at the bottom of each column and to color every pixel white until a white pixel was hit. This is what Piglet suggested below.

```
h, w = edges.shape[:2]
filled_from_bottom = np.zeros((h, w))
for col in range(w):
    for row in reversed(range(h)):
        if edges[row][col] < 255: filled_from_bottom[row][col] = 255
        else: break
```

---

### Method 1

Now this method uses some `numpy` tricks to speed up the operation.

First, for each column, find the maximum row index where there is a non-zero value in your edge image.

```
h, w = img.shape[:2]
row_inds = np.indices((h, w))[0] # gives row indices in shape of img
row_inds_at_edges = row_inds.copy()
row_inds_at_edges[edges==0] = 0 # only get indices at edges, 0 elsewhere
max_row_inds = np.amax(row_inds_at_edges, axis=0) # find the max row ind over each col
```

Then you can create a boolean array where every index greater than or equal to the max index is `True`:

```
inds_after_edges = row_inds >= max_row_inds
```

And then you can simply fill a new blank image with white at those new indices given by the boolean array

```
filled_from_bottom = np.zeros((h, w))
filled_from_bottom[inds_after_edges] = 255
```

---

### Method 2

This method is slightly more memory efficient and a little more speed efficient. It's the same basic premise as Method 1.

First, for each column, find the row index corresponding to the maximum in each column (which would be the color white in the edge image). Note that the function [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) will return the *first* instance of the maximum in an array while we want the last:

> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

So an easy way to get around that is to flip the array vertically, but then this gives us the indices into the reversed array. I think just explaining the one-liner is more intuitive after seeing it:

```
h, w = img.shape[:2]
max_row_inds = h - np.argmax(edges[::-1], axis=0)
```

The slice `[::-1]` inverts edges from top to bottom (alternatively could use `np.flipud`). Then since the array is flipped, `np.argmax` gives the index from the end, so `h - np.argmax` gives the index into the correctly oriented array.  And `np.argmax(..., axis=0)` means that we're taking the max over each column.

Now we can create the boolean array as before:

```
row_inds = np.indices((h, w))[0]
inds_after_edges = row_inds >= max_row_inds
```

The reason this method is a little better is because we're not creating a copy of an array, and we're removing an array assignment of many values.

---

### Speed tests

The first method is the simplest, but in Python, by far the slowest. Python loops are quite slow, while `numpy` operations are often implemented in C or Fortran-based methods, so they're quite snappy. I tested the difference with the following code:

```
import timeit
times = range(1000)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
A = [method0(edges) for t in times]
print("method0: ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
B = [method1(edges) for t in times]
print("method1: ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
C = [method2(edges) for t in times]
print("method2: ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

So each method ran 1000 times. Results:

```
method0: 62.79985192901222
method1: 0.9703722179983743
method2: 0.7760374149947893
```

We see that the final method is fastest, as expected; just a hair faster than method1, but not crazy. However, the difference between the loop based methods are huge.

---

### Output

[image: Filled from bottom]

Comment: You probably meant less efficient ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't, but maybe I am wrong. My prior solution required looping over the column indices, and this does not---so I meant that this was possibly faster than my answer pre-edit. I would appreciate any suggestions for speeding it up! Could use `argmax` on the reversed columns since the edges are white instead of setting non-edge vals to zero and then `amax`, but this still requires creating the `np.indices` array (though don't need to duplicate it)...any other suggestions?

Comment: See the answer by @Piglet.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just tested and my method without loops is around 100x faster than looping as Piglet suggested. Will post the code used to test.

Comment: Possibly when coded in Python, but x100 seems huge.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes indeed this is strictly due to working in Python. In C, loops would surely be the fastest way to do this. Python has a *lot* of overhead in loops, due to dynamic typing, whereas many of `numpy`s methods are written in C and Fortran so they're much more snappy. I ran this test multiple times and it's always 80-100x faster, with this particular image at least...not the most robust test of course.

Answer (score 1):

> This works by starting at the bottom of the image and proceeding
>   vertically pixel by pixel filling each empty black pixel until a
>   non-black pixel is seen. The filling then stops that vertical column
>   and proceeds with the next.

You don't need any fancy OpenCV functions for that. This can be accomplished by simply using a few loops.

You can do that in-place or using a separate output image which you initialize with zeros.

All you have to do is iterate over your image's columns starting from the bottom. If a pixel's value is zero set the output pixel to 255, once you hit a pixel that is not zero set the remaining pixels 0 (or leave them 0)